# RESTier PUT/PATCH not being called

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api2, odata, restier

currently i am working on a project with RESTier 1.0 NuGet-Package installed.
I am using a custom model builder with some DTOs.
To build the API i use Controllers that inherit from ODataController.
Querying or posting data is no problem so far.

When i try to Update a record with a PATCH or PUT request, the corresponding controller actions are not being called, but instead i get Exceptions.

1. First i did get ChangeSetPreparer is missing exceptions.
2. After a change i did get null reference exceptions.

So to avoid the first i have added a ChangeSetInitializer and a SubmitExecutor that i have found in some Github-Source (that i cannot remember anymore):

```
public class ExternalApi : ApiBase
{
    public ExternalApi(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) : base(serviceProvider)
    {
    }

public static new IServiceCollection ConfigureApi(Type apiType, IServiceCollection services)
{
    return ApiBase.ConfigureApi(apiType, services)
    .AddService<IModelBuilder, CustomModelBuilder>()
    .AddService<IChangeSetInitializer, ChangeSetInitializer>()
    .AddService<ISubmitExecutor, SubmitExecutor>();
}

private class ChangeSetInitializer : IChangeSetInitializer
{
    public Task InitializeAsync(SubmitContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        context.ChangeSet = new ChangeSet();
        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }
}

private class SubmitExecutor : ISubmitExecutor
{
    public Task<SubmitResult> ExecuteSubmitAsync(SubmitContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(new SubmitResult(context.ChangeSet));
    }
}
}
```

After adding those, the first problem seems to be solved but instead i am getting null reference exceptions with the following stacktrace:

> bei
>   Microsoft.Restier.Publishers.OData.RestierController.CreateResult(Type
>   resultType, Object result)    bei
>   Microsoft.Restier.Publishers.OData.RestierController.CreateUpdatedODataResult(Object
>   entity)    bei
>   Microsoft.Restier.Publishers.OData.RestierController.d__3f.MoveNext()
>   --- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde ---    bei
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    bei
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    bei
>   Microsoft.Restier.Publishers.OData.RestierController.d__20.MoveNext()
>   --- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde ---    bei
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    bei
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    bei
>   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.d__3`1.MoveNext()
>   --- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde ---    bei
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    bei
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    bei
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.d__0.MoveNext()
>   --- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde ---    bei
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    bei
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    bei
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.d__2.MoveNext()
>   --- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde ---    bei
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    bei
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    bei
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.d__0.MoveNext()
>   --- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde ---    bei
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.d__0.MoveNext()
>   --- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde ---    bei
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    bei
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    bei
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__1.MoveNext()
>   --- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde ---    bei
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__1.MoveNext()
>   --- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde ---    bei
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    bei
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    bei System.Web.Http.HttpServer.d__0.MoveNext()

These are examples for the action signatures that i use:

```
[EnableQuery]
public IQueryable<StoreDTO> Get()
[EnableQuery]
public SingleResult<StoreDTO> Get([FromODataUri] int key)
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post(StoreDTO store)
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Put([FromODataUri] int key, StoreDTO store)
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Patch([FromODataUri] int key, Delta<StoreDTO> store)
```

I tried diverse JSON-Objects that would match the DTO but i still get null reference exceptions even before the Put or Patch is being called.

Comment: I'm not sure if this helps, but I know you used to have to enable PUT and OPTIONS, and possibly PATCH request in a site as the framework wouldn't have this enabled by default.
Can you perform a PUT or PATCH request to a brand new web api endpoint as a test to confirm the verbs are enabled?

Comment: Or alternatively decorating the methods with the `AcceptVerbs` attribute to ensure those methods are being called

Comment: Actually i have build another RESTier service that only uses EntityFramework. Thar service works just fine with GET/POST/PUT/PATCH. I had to configure my applicationhost file and the webconfig. I use the same configuration for both services.

Comment: OK. I've removed my just-in-case answer as you've confirmed it works

Comment: @danrichardson The AcceptVerbsAttribute does not change the behavior. I tried it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution or at least a workaround.
I changed my WebApiConfig a little bit.

Instead of:
MapRestierRoute(...) from Microsoft.Restier.Publishers.OData.HttpConfigurationExtensions
i am using now:
MapODataServiceRoute(...) from System.Web.OData.Extensions.HttpConfigurationExtensions